# In a Views page with 3 arguments, 3rd argument default PHP being ignored if 2nd argument is not present

Tags: 6, views

Using Views 2, I have a View with 3 different vocabularies as arguments.

The first 2 are intended to be acquired from the URL, however the 3rd will only ever receive it's value from the Default Value PHP Code.

However if argument 2, which is optional, is not supplied, then Argument 3 is not evaluated.

**SOLUTION:**

Just to clarify where I landed:

The default option `Action to take if argument is not present` is always set to something (there is no `do nothing`).

It was already set to `Display all values` which was not working.

However `Provide default argument` > `Fixed Entry` > `"all"` while the argument wildcard is also `"all"` is allowing the 3rd argument to be evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always keep the optional args in the end otherwise define `Action to take if argument is not present` or at least set `Provide default argument` in argument configuration form.